# How do I filter a Django Model by month or year from a JSON dict?

Tags: python, json, django

I am trying to parse through a JSON database and filter by month or by year using Django and this is driving me up a wall since this should be simple.

An example of the dict key value pair in the JSON object is formatted as so:

```
"release_date": "2022-12-25T07:00:00",
```

From my views.py file, I set up this function to filter the model:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def yearList(request,pk):
    queryset = Character.objects.filter(release_date__year=pk)
    serializer = CharacterSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

And in my urls.py, I have this urlpattern (ignoring every other pattern)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('year/<str:pk>', views.CharacterList.as_view(), name="Character by year" )
]
```

Character model from models.py as requested:

```
class Character(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    game_origin = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    ref_id = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=20)
    ref_link = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    icon_link = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    sprite= models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    portrait= models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    attack= models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    special= models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    damaged= models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    voice_1 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    voice_2 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    line_1 = models.TextField(null=True)
    line_2 = models.TextField(null=True)
    summary = models.TextField(null=True)
    realm = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    release_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False)
    index = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " " + self.title
```

I followed [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#date) to get the idea to append "__year" to the release_date attribute when filtering the queryset. But it's not filtering the database, I'm still seeing all objects. Where am I going wrong? I can't look to filter by months if I can't even get the years filtered, so I'm focusing on the year first. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suggest using [`django-filter`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to help with this.

Comment: Can you add your Character model?

Comment: As for a more direct answer to your question, will you show an example request?

Comment: On a side note: I suggest renaming `pk` to `year` to more accurately describe what it represents.

Comment: You use `views.CharacterList` in your url pattern but have provided a view named  `yearList` in your question

Comment: Oh crap, that was the answer @IainShelvington which also explained why I couldn't recreate @ Code-Apprentice 's strategy. Whoops, what an embarrassing error. thank you guys so much for helping me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to add filters to a view is by accepting query parameters in the URL such as `http://localhost:8000/character/?year=1990`.

To implement this in your view, you get the parameters from `request.GET`:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def characters(request):
    queryset = Character.objects.filter(release_date__year=request.GET['year'])
    serializer = CharacterSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

The complexity of this grows quickly as you add more fields to filter on. The [`django-filter` library](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) provides a great API for configuring filters on all of your models so you don't have to write all of this yourself.